# UITableView Search Displayed Cell Error

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios, sdk

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];

definedNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Ohio", @"Newark", @"Steve", @"Coffee", nil];

definedAmounts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"5", @"100", @"1", @"72", nil];

}
```

That for example. So the numbers go with the name it matches but when i search it puts the numbers still in that order with the searched names

before search:
http://img855.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110327at302.png

searching for newark:
http://img849.imageshack.us/i/screenshot20110327at303.png

Newark should stay with the value 100.  Can someone explain how to do this to me please? i would appreciate it. also i have over 1000 entries and the values are shown in a custom cell.

thanks

Comment: How do you get your index array to display your information ?

Comment: I wouldn't separate data like that, why not just make an array with an array?  For example, `self.stuff = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Ohio",@"5", nil],[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Newark",@"100",nil],nil];`?  Then to set up your tableview, you can just use `[[stuff objectAtIndex:row] objectAtIndex:0];` for the name, and `[[stuff objectAtIndex:row] objectAtIndex:1];` for the number.

Comment: array with an array.  With over 1000 how would i put these into the tableview?

Comment: If you set up your array like that, then you can just use `[[stuff objectAtIndex:row] objectAtIndex:0];` for the name , just like I mentioned before in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: okay thanks. that worked to show in table with value but now when i go to search it crashes

Comment: You could use NSDictionary too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I wouldn't make all your data right at runtime if you have "1000" like you said.   I'd make a `plist` that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <array>
        <string>Ohio</string>
        <string>5</string>
    </array>
    <array>
        <string>Newark</string>
        <string>100</string>
    </array>
</array>
</plist>
```

And save it as `cities.plist`, for example.

Then in your initializing code, grab the plist and initialize your array with it:

```
NSString *citiesPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                           pathForResource:@"cities" 
                           ofType:@"plist"];
self.definedCities = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:citiesPath];
```

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, you can set up your cell simply by doing this:

```
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
NSString *city = [[cityData objectAtIndex:row] objectAtIndex:0]; //use index 1 if you want number
cell.textLabel.text = city;
return cell;
```

Makes it much simpler in my opinion.

Comment: i got that to work now

but this is my new problem it now crashes here because i havent specified which to search.  How would i do that?



    for (NSString *currentString in [self cityNames])
  {
   if ([currentString rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)

Comment: @Sean: Might want to ask that in a different question. :)